# Count/Group By/Order By is only showing the count of the most common value and not the string itself

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm querying a table to find the most common string in a column. However, it doens't seem to be working correctly. It should be returning the value of the most common string, but is instead returning the number of times the most common string exists. The query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(field_review_bar_tab_2_value) AS `Rows`
FROM (field_data_field_review_bar_tab_2)
GROUP BY (field_review_bar_tab_2_value)
ORDER BY `Rows` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Table structure, simplified, would be something to the effect of:

```
 -----------------------------------
| ID | field_review_bar_tab_2_value |
|----+----------------------------- |
| 1  | Food Drinks                  |
| 2  | Drinks                       |
| 3  | Food Drinks                  |
| 4  | Food                         |
 -----------------------------------
```

The query is recognizing that, in the example above, "Food Drinks" is the most common string in the column. But, the query is returning "2" instead of "Food Drinks". Any ideas as to why it would be making the correct query but returning the count of the result instead of the value of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `field_review_bar_tab_2_value` in the `SELECT` list as well. I've switched the aggregate to `COUNT(*)` here, and included the grouped column in the `SELECT`.

```
SELECT 
 field_review_bar_tab_2_value AS the_most_common_string,
 COUNT(*) AS `Rows`
FROM (field_data_field_review_bar_tab_2)
GROUP BY (field_review_bar_tab_2_value)
ORDER BY `Rows` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It's always something small isn't it? And apparently it wasn't working in the other tables either. I just thought it was. That's what I get for relying on my judgement from 3am the night before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting the count, not the value. I think you mean:

```
SELECT field_review_bar_tab_2_value
FROM field_data_field_review_bar_tab_2
GROUP BY field_review_bar_tab_2_value
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Since you're already grouping by the value in question, you can just do COUNT(*)...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify your query to return the field itself. Currently the query is only returning the COUNT because that's what is indicated in your select statement. Modify it as follows:

```
SELECT field_review_bar_tab_2_value AS `MostCommonString`, COUNT(field_review_bar_tab_2_value) AS `Rows` 
FROM (field_data_field_review_bar_tab_2) 
GROUP BY (field_review_bar_tab_2_value) 
ORDER BY `Rows` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```